# Diagnose shutdown delay

Tags: shutdown

Most of the time my shutdowns take 2 - 3 seconds.

Sometimes they take 30 - 45 seconds.

Here are the results after running journalctl -rb -1.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bva2e9cttr6j4f/shutdown.txt?dl=0

Can someone see something causing the long shutdown?

Comment: [This may help you](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2691#issuecomment-203255422), related to the line that takes ~90 seconds : `session-c1.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.`

Comment: @bistoco I did not see anything there that would help. There were some posts about session-c1.scope, but no answers.

Comment: Quote: The bug can be worked around by creating a file `/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf` with the following contents:

`kernel.core_pattern=core`